# Error al renderizar una tabla con datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nodejs, datatables

estoy intentándo conectar mi datatables con mi backend en nodejs para obtener datos del servidor, pero no logro que me cargue ningún dato, me pone Cargando... en la tabla y no sale nada, no me salta ningún error ni nada, este es el código de mi frontend:

```
let tablaDeUsuarios = $('#users-table').DataTable({
            columns: [
                { name: 'id', data: 'id' },
                { name: 'nombre', data: 'nombre' },
                { email: 'email', data: 'email' }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: [0] },
                { targets: [1] },
                {
                    targets: [2], render: (data, type, row) => {
                        return `${row.id} - ${data}`;
                    }
                },
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: '/pruebasDatos',
                dataSrc: 'data' 
            }
        });
```

Me renderiza la tabla y demás pero en el centro me sale cargando, y este es mi backend:

```
app.get('/pruebasDatos', (req, res) => {

let data = [{ "id": 1, "nombre": "Vivian", "email": "vbuddle0@umich.edu" },
    { "id": 2, "nombre": "Jania", "email": "jmaken1@dmoz.org" },
    { "id": 946, "nombre": "Sherman", "email": "skeyworthq9@gravatar.com" },
    { "id": 947, "nombre": "Masha", "email": "mgrabbqa@gravatar.com" },
    { "id": 948, "nombre": "Laverne", "email": "lwroutqb@admin.ch" },
    { "id": 949, "nombre": "Charmian", "email": "ckornalikqc@ehow.com" },
    { "id": 950, "nombre": "Buddy", "email": "blateqd@tamu.edu" },
];

return data;
```

});

Me llega, ya que si pongo un console.log(data) veo bien los datos, pero en el frontend no logro ver nada, ¿alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto para poder ver bien los datos? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo quitaría el arreglo `columns:`, no le veo sentido asignar el título de la columna si va a ser igual al nombre de la propiedad correspondiente. Si aún quieres usarlo, revisa la tercera columna, en lugar de `name: 'email'`, tienes `email: 'email'`

Comment: Y como puedo hacer que me renderize los daotos?? Muchas gracias